# How to draw simple bitmap text in a CALayer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I would like to draw lots of strings to a CALayer using sprite-sheet like images containing about eighteen fixed-width (9x15, in 1x and retina sizes) characters. I don't need any sort of color changing, converting from system fonts, or even size changing. Just simple bitmap font rendering.

Here's my sprite-sheet I'm trying to use (1x size):

[Image link](https://i.cubeupload.com/vboLE2.png)

I've tried using CoreText framesetters and NSAttributedString.draw, but they were too slow and too fancy for the amount of text I need to update each frame and the look and feel I am trying to achieve.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

@ToxicCaves64, maybe you can make your own true type font(.ttf) file, and put your eighteen fixed-width characters into your font file, then you can render your characters as text rather than images

Comment: The entire point of using bitmap rendering was that methods like Core Text to render ttfs were too slow for the sheer amount of text I need to render, so a ttf is not an option. This should be easy, as bitmap fonts have existed and have rendered at fast speeds since the 70s.